# ES6 destructuring assignment outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I'm developing a project based on `react` and I'm using `ES6` and babel transpile tools and plugins. I know about destructuring assignment inside constructor of class, it is like below:

```
~~~
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  ({
    name: this.name,
    family: this.family
  } = props);
}
~~~
```

The above code is instead of `this.name = props.name;` and `this.family = props.family;`.

But I don't use constructor because I used `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` and I don't need to have `constructor`, `this.state` and binding `this` to every class functions. I just declare `state` and declare functions as arrow function, see following sample:

```
class Sample extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    ~~~
  };

  handleSample = () => { ~~~ };

  ~~~
}
```

But now I don't know how I can destructuring my `this.props` outside of constructor inside body of class, and add them to `this`. I test some trying but they have syntax error:

```
({
  name: this.name,
  family: this.family
} = this.props);
```

How I can write it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to list all separately: (if you wanted to use in class)

```
name = this.props.name
family = this.props.family
```

But this seems unnecessary to me, you probably wanted to use in the state:

```
state = {
  name: this.props.name
  family: this.props.family
}
```

But if you need to use somewhere else, you can do:

```
render() {
  const { name, family } = this.props
```

Comment: Thanks to you dear  @BhojendraRauniyar, But please attention to my question. I want destructuring inside class properties, I know it can done in `state` or `render` function.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

1.You could use the constructor and pass the props to state. If you use arrow functions you don't have to do the binding for every function.(Although creating functions and binding compiles faster than arrow functions).

2.You could use the props inside the state and do something like this:

```
state={prop1: this.props.prop1,prop2: this.props.prop2,...}
```

And then use the state instead

3.Another solution is to use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) which is a new feature that enables your to use state in functional components and also use props by passing them as argument in your function declaration. So your component would become from this:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
   .....
  }
  .
  .
  .
  render() {
    const {prop1, prop2, ...}=this.props
    return {......};
  }
}
```

to this:

```
 function Example(props) {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const {prop1, prop2, ...} = props;
  .
  .
  .
  return (
    ....
  );
}
```

Comment: but he wants to destructure prop values in class member variables.

Comment: @VishalGulati yes you are correct he should do the destructuring in the render() method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dear @AristosManolarakis, but I wanna destructuring  them in class not inside `render` some functions interpret before render function. so your method is not useful. thanks.

Comment: @AlferedoGorrino What do you mean some functions interpret before render function? You mean some things happen before the first render or functions that work as callbacks? Is there any link to your code?

Comment: Dear @AristosManolarakis, if I destructuring  my props and add them to `this`, inside render function. the outer functions inside class can not access to them.